# Mac - Unable to run Android Device Monitor

Tags: android

When I tried to open Android Device Monitor through Android Studio: Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor.

It always shows the following screen shot [An error has occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdH5y.png).

I have also tried updating my JDK to version 8 but it didn't help.

I am using sql lite to use database in my app and I don't know any other way to check whether my table has been created or not.

So what else should I do? Is there any other way so open Android Device monitor? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the log that message is telling you to read? What did you find there?

Comment: Its more than a 50 pages log. And I don't understand what its saying. here's some part of it                                                                                              !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-19 21:41:15.723
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)

Comment: Try the action that fails and THEN check the last 100 lines of it. Then you can bring a full stacktrace of the error and please, add it to your question (editing it) instead of adding a comment :)